# on form submit slide page to div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have form and one div named "success". when form is submited "success" div has been shown.

i am trying to do that, when form submitted, page slide to "success" div.

my code is.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function () {
        $('.success').show(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut();
        $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: its too long. how can i?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What is happening with your code at the moment that you dont want?

Comment: code is working, but i want to do that, when my form is submitted. the page slide down to the bottom or elsewhere.

Comment: @hemsbhardiya just post you `div named "success".` html code

Comment: You can an use `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: xxx}, 1000);` to scroll the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Slide Effect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) here like:

```
$('.success').show('slide').delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

[**Fiddle Demo #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4EF5/)

**UPDATE**

For scrolling to the `success` div, you can do this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.success').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

[**Fiddle Demo #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/)

Comment: its working. but my question remain same. my "success"div is at top of the page. so i need that when form is submitted page scroll to top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "mail.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function () {
  var success = $('.success'); //caching the element to enhance performance
    success.show();
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
      success.fadeOut(5000);
    },1000);
    $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
  }
});
```